# Auto redirect to wp-admin/post when update post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a problem
When i update a post

[image]

My page Auto redirect to wp-admin/post. This is a blank page

[image]

Please help me!
Thanks so much!

Comment: `WP_DEBUG` make it true so you can see the errors, and any hook is called within plugin or theme which cause this issue.
Switch with default theme and disabled the plugin step by step.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i'm solved it.
Turn on WP_DEBUG then then I found out there are spaces in the file function.php.
You save my day. Thanks so much

Comment: Ok then let me add as a answer so you can like my answer :)

Comment: Ok, I did . have fun :)

Comment: Thank you @jackmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps**

1) **WP_DEBUG** make it true so you can see the errors, if any hook is called within plugin or theme which cause this issue.

2) If still error/issue is not found then Switch with default theme and disabled the plugin step by step.